# Nginx shows me 404 page from time to time

Tags: nginx

I ran into very strange Nginx problem - it is sometimes can open my website, but sometemis can't (shows 404 page). I just click "reload" on webpage every 3 seconds, an sometimes I just get my fully functional site, sometimes 404 with wrong nginx version (I have installed 1.22 version, but 404 page shows 1.18)

My configuration is very common - ubuntu 20.04, nginx 1.22, Laravel website. My nginx config (stored in `api.website.com`):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.website.com;
    root /var/www/apiwebsite/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I also have a `website.com` config, it is proxy for Nuxt - it works without problem:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}

server {
    listen          80;             # the port nginx is listening on
    server_name     website.com;    # setup your domain here

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000; # set the address of the Node.js instance here
    }
}
```

Do someone have any ideas what it can be?

Comment: Things goings stranger and stranger - 404 page appears only in chrome-based browsers (Chrome, Edge), but Firefox and Insomnia (Rest client) shows everything without hassle

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was in Chrome (and chrome-based browsers) - for somewhat reason it was make requests sometimes to my server, sometimes to other. Maybe problem was in DNS refreshing, but strange that this behavior cointinues for few hours even after Firefox already get correct info.